# Best practice for iterating through an iterable until either a condition is met or the iterable has been fully iterated over in Java

Tags: java

Sorry if title isn't super clear.
I have two ways to do this where: `c` is an iterable of Objects

```
boolean condition = false;
for (Object o : c) {
    if (meetsCondition(o)) {
        condition = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

```
boolean condition = false;
Iterator<Object> iter = c.iterator();
while (!condition && iter.hasNext()) if (meetsCondition(iter.next())) condition = true;
```

If Object `o` meets a condition that is described using the method `meetsCondition()` then I would like to update the result and stop looping as the program only requires one of the objects to meet this condition.

Unsure as to what is the best practice as have been informed that using `break` is not good practice.

Thank you.

Comment: Using `break;` is fine, and this is exactly what it's for.  There are a couple of other alternatives - one is to refactor your loop out into its own method, which can `return true;` when the condition is met, and `return false;` after the loop.  Another alternative is to use streams (if your iterable is a `Collection`), with the `anyMatch` method.  As far as what "best practice" is, that's really a matter of opinion, which is why I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many more ways to achieve that. I prefer "streams", which would look like this:

```java
var condition = c.stream()
   .takeUntil(this::meetsCondition)
   .findAny()
   .isPresent();
```

Many "senior devs" are more familiar with your first solution. Because Streams are very new.
If I had the chance to choose between your solutions, I would take the first one.
The second example is very complex and hard to read.

### Edit

As suggested in the comments (thanks [Dawood ibn Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/dawood-ibn-kareem)), it can be just:

```java
var condition = c.stream()
   .anyMatch(this::meetsCondition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
c.stream()
  .filter(o -> meetsCondition(o)) // Find the appropriate values
  .findAny() // Take any object
  .ifPresent(o -> doSomething(o)); // If there is an object do something with it.
```